# How to visualize this data?

Tags: data-visualization, r

[image]

Here I have shown the first two lines of my data frame. It goes on for a number of lines.

I am wanting to make plots to show what is happening over time . e.g a plot showing the sequence of grip changes over time and who is making the changes P1 or P2 .

I am using R, so things I can implement in R would be relevant - and guidance on how to do so would be especially useful.

I have tried using code such as `plot(mydata$Start,mydata$Name)` and `stripchart(mydata$Name)` but I have not been successful. In some cases I get an error such as

```
Error in stripchart.default(mydata$Name) : invalid first argument
```

I am unsure how to approach this. Should it not be a data frame maybe ?

Comment: What are the types of the variables? What types are the plot commands you call expecting?

Comment: @Glen_b, the variables are all coming as "factor" when I cheek their class type. I thought R would interpret text as a string and numbers as integers or ideally time int his case . My assumption was wrong though.

Comment: I've edited the question to come closer to what I was trying to suggest in chat; I suspect I didn't convey it clearly. Feel free to change it, of course.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues here.

The problem is not that it's a data frame, it's that you're not giving it numbers where it needs numbers. It's not even a problem that the variables (other than time) are factors.

You should be able to convert time to numbers okay, but even if your text was all strings, that wouldn't help.

Note that when you do `stripchart(mydata$Name)` you're passing it *names* when it expects *numbers*.

Comment: ahh right . Thanks. I had thought I'd be able to plot a strip chart of Name's and R would just plot them in the sequence they occur in my data frame. Looks like I have ALOT of reading to do.

Comment: It sounds like you think a stripchart does something other than what it actually does. It's not for ordered sequences of data at all.

Comment: hmmm maybe I have misunderstood what the strip chart does. I had thought it'd place time along the x axis and then there wouldnt be a Y axis as such rather (based on the x axis showing time) it'd show me at what time a certain variable of my choosing occurred. e.g. it show me time along x axis and at what the corresponding Name value was at that time. Thankls for you input and help it is appreciated.

Comment: Nope. You could maybe fiddle with it to do something like that, but I think there are better ways. How many different events are there?

Comment: I am only using 18 in total with this set (it is a learning set for me before I tackle bigger sets)

Comment: In the worst case, how many different kinds of event?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15802/discussion-between-b-miller-and-glen-b).

Answer (score 2):

I attempted to create a dummy data frame similar to your data using the following code:

```
data <- data.frame(Grip.Type=rep(c('RH','LH'),times=100),
                   Start=seq(from=0.5,to=2,length.out=200),
                   Name=ifelse(rnorm(n=200,mean=1,sd=2)>0,'P1','P2'),
                   Position=c('RH : L/Knee','LH : R/Elbow'))
```

(Please let me know if this is the way your data looks like)

From this data frame I have attempted to create the following plot using the `ggplot2` library:

Plot 01:

```
p1 = ggplot(data)+
    geom_point(aes(x=Start,y=Name,col=Name),size=1.5)+
    ggtitle('Plot 1')
p1
```

[image: Sequence of grip changes]

Does this look like what you are looking for?

Comment: This is definitely headed down the path I am ultimately aiming to go down. My original data is from a CSV file that I have exported from another program.

Comment: [Jittering the points](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_jitter.html) would be much more informative here.

Comment: It would have, had there been more numerical parameters to represent the data in a distributed format on both the axes.But, as it is right now, only the time axis is numerical and other variables are categorical, so the y axis would never make sense in this case as each categorical level must be shown at the same value on y-axis.

Comment: This is definitely headed down the path I am ultimately aiming to go down. My original data is from a CSV file that I have exported from another program. One of my goals is to have it similar to the plot above but to have each point indicate what the position change was. Ultimately it becomes slightly more complex as there are apporixmately 15 different positions that happen and in same cases the reoccur throughout the time.

Comment: One question we are wanting to answer is are there any sequences/patterns  of grip change that reoccur and then we would go and investigate why these are happening and what is leading to them.

Comment: Tell me if I am getting this in the right way: Over time, the intend is to show the Name of the person who made the change and the type of the change, is that correct? Try changing the `color` parameter to 'Position' or the `shape` parameter to 'Position' in the same plot. That might give a better view of Position changes done by a each person over a period of time.

Comment: :-) Yes that is it, you summarized it nicely. That is exactly one of the things we are trying to establish.

Comment: People use jittered points exactly when the axis is categorical, as the points otherwise are heavily obfuscated by overlapping one another. As long as the difference between the categories is larger than the difference within categories it is easy to see which axis label the groups belong to. See `ggplot(data, aes(x=Start,y=Name,col=Name))+geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(width = 0, height = 0.1))` - can you not tell from that graphic which value of `Name` each point is associated with?

Comment: Exactly my point, you can interprete the name from y-axis directly. Putting a categorical variable on y-axis for a jitter plot would create a slight variation in the y-coordinate of the points (setting `height`)....but the points are already 'non-overlapping' {Since there can be only one point per person at a given moment in time}.So using jitter for this data wouldn't give any extra information. Changing `color=Position` or `shape=Position` would add one more bit of inormation i.e. the type of change made by the person being shown on the y-axis. Or am I missing something that you are trying t

Comment: Ahhh..so using shapes would be a god idea wouldn't it ? As I would be able to have a visual search to see if I can find trends occurring where creation shapes are repeated in a sequence (for example)